# Run one specific action of an action function in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

**Background:**

in my WordPress theme I have the below action functions, which consolidate several hooks, e.g. several functions are consolidated into:

`'single_job_listing_meta_start'`

```
public static function template_tags() {
    add_action( 'single_job_listing_start', array( __CLASS__, 'single_job_listing_start' ), 10 );

    add_action( 'listify_single_job_listing_meta', array( __CLASS__, 'enqueue_scripts' ) );
    add_action( 'listify_single_job_listing_meta', array( __CLASS__, 'single_job_listing_meta' ) );

    add_action( 'single_job_listing_meta_start', array( __CLASS__, 'the_secondary_image' ), 7 );
    add_action( 'single_job_listing_meta_start', 'listify_the_listing_title', 10 );
    add_action( 'single_job_listing_meta_start', 'listify_the_listing_location', 20 );
    add_action( 'single_job_listing_meta_start', 'listify_the_listing_category', 30 );

    add_action( 'single_job_listing_meta_after', 'listify_the_listing_rating' );

    add_action( 'listify_single_job_listing_actions', array( __CLASS__, 'the_actions' ) );
    add_action( 'listify_single_job_listing_actions_after', array( __CLASS__, 'submit_review_link' ) );

    add_action( 'listify_single_job_listing_cover_end', array( __CLASS__, 'cover_gallery' ) );
}
```

**Desired outcome**

However, I actually need the more granular functions behind it, i.e.

```
array( __CLASS__, 'the_secondary_image' ) 
'listify_the_listing_title'
'listify_the_listing_location'
'listify_the_listing_category'
'listify_the_listing_rating'
```

**Solution attempt**

By trying I was able to execute the last 4 hooks of the above, simply via eg

```
<?php listify_the_listing_rating(); ?>
```

However, I have two questions:

1. given these are all hooked (consolidated) into `'single_job_listing_meta_start'`, is there a way to call this (consolidated) action and execute only a specific hook from it? If yes, how would be the code for example?
2. Whilst I was able to execute the above hook functions 2-5 via     `<?php listify_the_listing_rating(); ?>`, how would I execute the first hook `array( __CLASS__, 'the_secondary_image'`? I tried `<?php array( __CLASS__, 'the_secondary_image') ?>` which didn't work.

Comment: _“is there a way to call this (consolidated) action and execute only a specific hook from it?”_ - your function itself does not _execute_ any of those hooks/filters, it only adds them to be executed later. _“how would I execute the first hook”_ - why would you want to do that manually in the first place? What are you trying to _achieve_ here? It rather sounds like you might have misunderstood how the whole hook thing works in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to execute the secondary image code with the following:

Listify_WP_Job_Manager_Template_Single_Listing::the_secondary_image();

I believe it refers to the template file (first part of the code) and then the function (second part).